# char* or wchar_t* to textbox

Tags: c++, winforms

char* cbuffer;
    wchar_t* wbuffer;
    cbuffer = _getcwd(NULL, 0);
    wbuffer = _wgetcwd(NULL, 0);

Also, I have textbox1 and textbox2. How can I put cbuffer in textbox1 and wbuffer in textbox2. Thanks.

Comment: What API/framework/library are you using?

Comment: I assume you're talking about Windows?

Comment: And what is a textbox? As written, this is not really a question.

Comment: Windows Forms Application from VS2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert the C++ string to CTS (Common Type System) System.String used by .NET.

[See this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b620dhe.aspx)